# Filling data from an oracle table is not taking date and time

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I am trying to fill a datatable with data from an oracle table. While fetching the data I uses oracle connection, and Oracle data adapter in c# to fill a data table. The actual oracle table has a column with datatype date .This column has both date and time in this format "10/26/2006 3:52:18 PM' ,but when it is filled to a datatable it takes only the date .Please help

Here is my code ,

string oquery = "SELECT * FROM table_NAME WHERE INSERT_DATE between to_date ('" + startdate[i] + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND to_date ('" + enddaterr[i] + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ";

```
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(oquery, con);
                OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                oda.Fill(dtb);
```

Comment: Show your code.... or take a look on how do you format your column.

Comment: how you are filling them what is the query

Comment: Here is my code , 
string oquery = "SELECT * FROM table_NAME WHERE INSERT_DATE between to_date ('" + startdate[i] + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND to_date ('" + enddaterr[i] + "', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ";
                    

                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(oquery, con);
                    OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                    oda.Fill(dtb);

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried casting you date in C#

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

And when retrieving it from Oracle cast it back, using Oracle format

> SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM') from dual

```
using (OracleDataReader dr =  Zurich.Common.OracleDataAccess.ExecuteReader(cn, CommandType.Text, mySQL))
        {
            if (dr.HasRows) // file exists in DB
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    currentDays = Convert.ToInt16(((DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date) - Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0])).TotalDays);
                    Console.WriteLine(CheckDate(Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0])));

                    lbBugs.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:dd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss}", dr[0]) + ": " + dr.GetString(1) + " : " + currentDays);
```

Comment: Thank you fro your reply ...  unless others who were eager to down vote only ,you gave me a reply .

I tried to_char .but it is not working.......

In toad even without to_char , select statement returns the date and time value  but when I am trying to fill a  datatable with same query from c# , date  is coming but time part is not showing

Comment: ok I checked my code.. I am a fan of just getting dates as strings and then using them as I need too. so I would do a  using (OracleDataReader dr =Zurich.Common.OracleDataAccess.ExecuteReader(cn, CommandType.Text, mySQL)).... then  if (dr.HasRows).... while (dr.Read())...then just calc by currentDays = Convert.ToInt16(((DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date) - Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0])).TotalDays); or dispay with  lbBugs.Items.Add(String.Format("{0:dd/M/yyyy H:mm:ss}", dr[0]) + ": " + dr.GetString(1) + " : " + currentDays);....

Comment: I will tell my scenario... I am trying to copy data from an oracle database table to sql table ...  This oracle table is currently working and with in a second atleast five records will be added. 
I have to copy the whole data once and after that within ten minutes I have to check for any updates in the oracel table  if yes will copy it to sql table.....
Issue is when I am accessing the oracle table through toad all the date columns shows date and time in the format "10/26/2006 3:52:18 PM'"
.... But when it is copied to sql table time part is disappearing

Comment: just check each point in chain.... make sure time in orcal sql...then check c# for time then pass to sql check that. With SQL you can run analyser and see if incoming inserts/ updates have time in field